# trying to convert rcp Application into log4j2 but ibatise and DB logs are not getting into log file

Tags: eclipse-rcp, log4j2

Added this in log4j2.xml but queries are not getting printed to log file

```
    <AsyncLogger name="com.ibatis" level="INFO" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="FILE" />
    </AsyncLogger>
```

Comment: Eclipse RCP apps normally don't know anything about log4j2 - so what have you done to set that up? Please take the [tour] and learn how to [ask].

Comment: have multiple plugin projects to build 1 rcp application. added log4j2-api and log4j2-core and jcl bridge dependencies in classpath of plugin project. we are using mybatis3.5.7 but query and resultset logs are not getting printed in log file

Comment: what changes should I need to make RCP know about log4j2?